# Models load() usage

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2

Can someone enligthen me ,what is the real usage of load method if setting post params can  be directly set to models attributes? Thanks

`$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());`

vs

`$model->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post();`

Answer (score 1):

As you can easy see in  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail

> load  Populates the model with input data.  load() gets the 'FormName'
>   from the model's formName() method (which you may override), unless
>   the $formName parameter is given.
>
> the data being populated is subject to the safety check by setAttributes().

see also http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of load($data, $formName) is to return boolean true if the expected $formName is found in $data. Thus, you can bypass the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['FormName'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['FormName'];
    do_something_here;
}
```

with

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
if ($model->load($post)) {
    do_something_here;
}
```

It's interesting for more, different kind of models:

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
if ($modelA->load($post) && $modelB->load($post) && $modelC->load($post)) {
    do_something_if_all_models_are_loaded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`load()` will only assign attributes that have got validation rules assigned to them in current scenario so you are able to verify them.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have gone through this or not .. .but it's pretty much clear here : www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail